# I get this error when running my nodejs code: ' TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined. '

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've made a basic node.js application including a controller and a service. I keep getting this error when i try to run the application. It should be a get method for returning any table based on the passed 'namespace' and 'table' parameters.

Controller:

```
var express = require('express');
const testService = require ('../services/testService');

const getAnyController = async(req, res, next) => {

    var table = req.params.table;
    var namespace = req.params.namespace;
    table = table.toUpperCase();
    namespace = namespace.toLowerCase();
    var client = req.db;

    try{
        var serviceResponse = await testService.GetAny(table, namespace, client);
        res.status(200).send(serviceResponse);
        next();
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error.message);
        res.status(500) && next(error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getAnyController
}
```

Service:

```
var express = require('express');

function GetAny(table, namespace, client) {

    var getScript = 'SELECT * from ' + namespace + '.' + table;

    client.query(getScript, (err, response) => {

        if(err) {
            return 'Error: ' + err.toString();
        }
        return response;
    });
}

module.exports = {
    GetAny
};
```

Index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const testController = require('../controllers/testController');

router.get("/test/:namespace/:table", (req, res) => {
    testController.getAnyController(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635
return fn.apply(this, arguments);
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
at next (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:210:14)
at Function.handle (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at router (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/server.js:46:33)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
npm
ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
errno 1
npm ERR! js@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the js@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: What is in `/home/vcap/app/server.js` on line  46?

Comment: Does it fail on `next()` in `getAnyController`? `getAnyController` looks like middleware's callback and you don't pass `next` in `testController.getAnyController(req, res);`

Comment: It doesn't fail in the controller, I just added the controller layer and I got the same error before I created it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. The router was not defined in server.js